# how can I auto-clear the text box and hide the keypad in android

Tags: android

1. How can I auto-clear the text box after I clicked the ADD button (inserted data) into database?
2. How to link the DONE button on keyPad(prompt out when user wants to type ) to my ADD button?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use an OnEditorActionListener, where you click the button, hide the keyboard, and set the text to "".  Like this:

```
   mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            mButton.performClick();
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            v.setText("");
            return true;
        }
});
```